# How do I configure the SpringSource OBR in Eclipse?

Tags: repository, osgi, springsource

If I understand it properly, SpringSource has a public OBR which contains OSGi bundles for many third party jars. I would like to use it in Eclipse, but I can't get Eclipse to connect to it.

I have tried:

```
http://ebr.springsource.com
```

It hangs there for ages, and returns as error:

```
Error reading update site http://ebr.springsource.com.
The XML stream is not a valid default "site.xml" file.
The root tag is not site.
```

And I have tried:

```
http://ebr.springsource.com/repository
```

Which returns quickly as error:

```
No repository found at http://ebr.springsource.com/repository.
```

So, what URL am I meant to use?

[EDIT] Made some research after getting my first answer. I found [this site](http://sigil.codecauldron.org/OBR+Repository) which claims to have a list of public OBR repositories:

```
OSGi Bundle Repository:
http://www.osgi.org/obr/browse?cmd=repository&_xml=1

Spring Enterprise Bundle Repository:
http://sigil.codecauldron.org/spring-external.obr
http://sigil.codecauldron.org/spring-release.obr
```

But none of them work with Eclipse either. I'm just more confused now.

What I (think I) understand is:

1) SpringSource EBR is a Repository of OSGi Bundles, without being a "OSGi Bundle Repository". This makes no sense to me. What's the point?

2) An "OSGi Bundle Repository" is just a XML file that defines the configuration of a Repository of OSGi Bundles.

So, If I give http://sigil.codecauldron.org/spring-external.obr to Eclipse, instead of http://ebr.springsource.com, I would expect Eclipse to use the content of that file to access http://ebr.springsource.com, but it doesn't work either.

So which one of the possible reason is it:

1) http://sigil.codecauldron.org/spring-external.obr is outdated or wrong

2) http://sigil.codecauldron.org/spring-external.obr is not compatible with Eclipse (apparently, it works with Apache Felix)

3) An "Eclipse Update Site" is NOT an OBR (and neither is it a Maven Repository), although it should also contain OSGi bundles. If that is the case, then it wouldn't make much sense either, since Eclipse is OSGi-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SpringSource EBR is not an Eclipse Update Site, so it cannot be used this way. It is also not an OBR, at least currently. But Eclipse PDE doesn't use OBR anyway (though [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org/) does).

You can use it as a Maven repository, I think.

Comment: Hi Sebastian. Answer (3) is correct: an Eclipse Update Site is not an OBR. They are in fact "p2 Repositories". P2 is just a different kind of repository index, and I'm not sure if one exists for the SpringSource EBR content.